# Criando uma fila encadeada com matriz de char dentro da scruct

Tags: c

O problema que estou tendo é que preciso colocar dentro da struct uma qntd x de string de 281 character.

Onde um bloco pode ter 5, 10 ... ifinito de strings, eu pensei em fazer matriz, e até onde eu comecei deu certo, pórem quando comecei a imprimir os char que começou os erros.

Se tiver alguma forma até mais facil, agradeço se alguem poder ajudar, e sim ta cheio de gambiarras e até rendundancias.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct no{
    int qndtweet;

    struct no * prox;
    struct no * ant;
    char twe[][281];
}NO;

NO *inicio = NULL;
NO *fim = NULL;
int tam = 0;
int count = 0;
char tweet[281];

void adicionar(int qntd);
void digite();
void imprimir();

int main(){
    system("clear");
    int qntd=0, qntdt=0;
    printf("Digite a quantidade de tweets por bloco: ");
    scanf("%d", &qntd);
    getchar();
    printf("Digite a quantidade de tweets: ");
    scanf("%d", &qntdt);
    getchar();

    for(int i = 0; i < qntdt; i++){
        adicionar(qntd);
    }

    imprimir();
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void adicionar(int qntd){
    if(qntd == 0){
        printf("Qntd == 0\n");
        return;
    }
    digite();

    if(tam == 0 || count == qntd){ // INICIALIZACAO DO BLOCO
        NO *novo =(NO*) malloc (sizeof(NO));
    
        novo->qndtweet = qntd;
        strcpy(novo->twe[0], tweet);
        novo->prox = NULL;
        novo->ant = NULL;
    
        if(inicio == NULL && fim == NULL){ //tam == 0 - lista vazia :D
            inicio = novo;
            fim = novo;
            tam++;
        }
            
        else if(inicio != NULL && fim != NULL){// no fim da lista
            fim->prox = novo;
            novo->ant = fim;
            fim = novo;
            tam++;
        }
        else{// no fim
            printf("insercao invalida! :/");
        }
        count = 0;
    }
    else if(count < qntd && tam != 0){ //Aqui add dentro do bloco que ja existe
        NO *aux = fim;
        strcpy(aux->twe[count], tweet);
    }
    else
        printf("insercao invalida! :/");
    count++;
}

void digite(){
    int lent;
    printf("Tweet: ");
    fgets(tweet, sizeof tweet, stdin);
    lent = strlen(tweet);
    if (tweet[lent - 1] == '\n') {
    /* nome completo, com ENTER incluido */
        tweet[--lent] = 0; // apagar o ENTER
    } 
    else {
    /* ENTER e possivelmente outros caracteres ficaram no buffer */
    int ch;
    do 
        ch = getchar(); 
    while (ch != '\n'); // limpa caracteres extra
    }
}

void imprimir(){
    NO *aux = inicio;
    int i;
    printf("\n*--------------------Imprimindo--------------------*\n");
    if(inicio == NULL){
        printf("Vazio!!\n");
    }else{
        
        printf("Tam: %d\n", tam);
        printf("Count: %d\n", count);
        printf("Qntd: %d\n", aux->qndtweet);
        
        
        do{
            printf("\n");
            for(i=0; i < tam ; i++){
                for(int j=0; j < aux->qndtweet; j++){
                    printf("Bloco[%d]\n        Tweet[%d]: %s \n",i+1, j, aux->twe[j]);
                    //if(i == tam-1 && aux->qndtweet - j == count)
                       // break;
                }
                aux = aux->prox;
            }
        } while(aux != NULL);
    }
    printf("*-------------------------------------------------*\n");
    free(aux);
}
```

[Codico rodando com exemplo do erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfSah.png)

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Seu programa não está bom. Assim é frágil e vai dar um trabalho enorme para terminar.

Escreva em torno dos dados. A única estrutura que tem em seu código é de um suposto nó de uma lista. É pouco.

E nunca misture os dados com a estrutura da lista ou nunca vai poder usar sua lista em outro código ou outra lista nesse código. E toda a razão de escrever um programa é poder usar e reusar uma solução.

**Seu dado é um tweet**

Podia ser

```
typedef struct
{
    char txt[281];
} Tweet; // um tweet
```

Mas os tweets vem em blocos. Um bloco podia ser

```
    typedef struct
{
    int     N;  // quantos?
    Tweet** tweet;
}   Tweets; // o bloco
```

E deve dar certo, já que TODO programa em C tem uma estrutura dessas: o protótipo de `main` é algo como

```
    int main( int argc, char** argv);
```

E os Tweets vão numa lista ligada.O que é uma lista?

Podia ser

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t limite;

    Node* ini;
    Node* fim;
} Lista;
```

Pois é: a lista é de nós. E cada nó aponta para um registro de dados. Que pode ser qualquer coisa.

```
typedef Tweets Dado;  // essa lista e de Tweets
```

E assim pode reusar as funções da lista.

E como seria um nó?

```
 typedef struct st_node
{
    struct st_node* ant;
    struct st_node* prox;
    Dado*           D;
} Node; // um no da lista, que aponta para um Dado
```

O simples: um nó aponta para um dado, para o próximo nó e para o nó anterior.

#### um esqueleto mais completo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char txt[281];
} Tweet; // um tweet

    typedef struct
{
    int     N;  // quantos?
    Tweet** tweet;
}   Tweets; // o bloco

typedef Tweets Dado;  // essa lista e de Tweets

typedef struct st_node
{
    struct st_node* ant;
    struct st_node* prox;
    Dado*           D;
} Node; // um no da lista, que aponta para um Dado

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t limite;

    Node* ini;
    Node* fim;
} Lista;

Lista* l_apaga(Lista*);
Lista* l_cria(int);
int    l_insere(Dado*, Lista*);
int    l_mostra(Lista*, const char*);

Tweets* t_apaga(Tweets*);
Tweets* t_gera(int);
int     t_mostra(Tweets* twe);


int main(void) { return 0; };
```

Compare com o modo como escreveu e se não entender as diferenças quando der tempo posso aumentar o exemplo até um programa completo